# How to performance profiling on CakePHP1.3

Tags: performance, cakephp-1.3

My Cake app is very heavy.

so I'd like to research for reason why.

Could you recommend how to take some performance report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it running. Then pause or interrupt it manually with Ctrl-C or whatever, and display the call stack.

Since it's so slow, the chance that you *won't* catch it doing the slow thing is very small.

[Here's an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295799/how-to-improve-performance-of-this-code/4299378#4299378) (It's in python, but same idea.)

Answer (score 0):

you could check [debuggable.com/posts/spotting-performance-leaks-in-your-application:480f4dd5-8a74-4390-b17f-445ccbdd56cb](http://debuggable.com/posts/spotting-performance-leaks-in-your-application:480f4dd5-8a74-4390-b17f-445ccbdd56cb). Yes it is outdated but gives you some hints how to collect performance report.
Or try to use [xdebug.org](http://xdebug.org)